# Spring Data reactive repositories page count and total count

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb

In spring Data, I can easily perform queries such as:

```
Page<MyClass> findByX(String x, Pageable pageable);
```

In `reactive Spring data` (MongoDB), I couldn't find a valid way to paginate the result.

```
Mono<Page<MyClass>> findByX(String x, Pageable pageable);
```

seems like a good candidate but fails with an error that requires usage of `Flux.buffer(size, skip)`

If there is no valid way to do it, Is there a way to get the query total count without actually performing the query once without Page?

Comment: You have to change `Mono<Page<MyClass>>` to `Flux<MyClass>` then in your repository you will be able to add the result to the content pageable and get the total items in the db.

Comment: it wasn't the question. Of course, I can use Flux (and this is what using because couldn't find a way to get the Page data). the question was how to get Page data as part of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Reactive Spring Data MongoDB repositories do not provide paging in the sense of paging how it's designed for imperative repositories. Imperative paging requires additional details while fetching a page. In particular:

- The number of returned records for a paging query
- Optionally, total count of records the query yields if the number of
  returned records is zero or matches the page size to calculate the
  overall number of pages

Both aspects do not fit to the notion of efficient, non-blocking resource usage. Waiting until all records are received (to determine the first chunk of paging details) would remove a huge part of the benefits you get by reactive data access. Additionally, executing a count query is rather expensive, and increases the lag until you're able to process data.

You can still fetch chunks of data yourself by passing a Pageable (PageRequest) to repository query methods:

```
Flux<MyClass> findByX(String x, Pageable pageable);
```

Spring Data will apply pagination to the query by translating Pageable to LIMIT and OFFSET.

[Spring Documentation says:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.reactive)

[image]

You can try the below code, I believe it should work for you to get the count

```
Mono<Long> countByXxxx(String x);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do understand (and missed that part in the docs) that spring doesn't support it but I'm not entirely convinced regarding your answer. the fact that the request supports Pagination means that anyhow, You wait for the data (the chunks) to return and for the (specified page size) records. the "price" of the count query doesn't really matter - a simple zip operation is suffice. There is 1 major functionality that is working and implemented with MVC and not with webflux. not sure that there is a good reason behind it beside the fact that "it's just not support"

Comment: Going by your question .."If there is no valid way to do it, Is there a way to get the query total count without actually performing the query once without Page"... I believe my answer above suffices the query.

Comment: Now coming to point on how pagination work for MongoDb repository when used in a reactive way we have to understand that using a findByXXX method, Spring Data Mongo Reactive provides a variant to accept a pageable argument, but the findAll(reactive version) does not include such a variant, you have to do skip in the later operations if you really need the pagination feature. You can find further information on how different patterns are used during  pagination in this [link - Paging with the Bucket Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
public Mono<Page<Role>> findByTenantId(TenantId id, Pageable page) {
    return roleRepository.countByTenantId(id)
            .zipWith(roleRepository.findByTenantId(id, page).collectList())
            .map(countAndItems -> new PageImpl<Role>(countAndItems.getT2(),
                    page, countAndItems.getT1()));
}
```

It is true that in this way both streaming of result items only starts after the complete page has been loaded and we need to count toal results first.